# Loading Server Configs in Isomorphic redux applications

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, isomorphic-javascript

We have a common logger utility which uses Bunyan framework to log the information to files etc.

```
import logger '../Logger';
```

So i am using Isomorphic redux applications where action files executes
both on client and server side.

```
export function getTodos(params) {

  const API_URL = config.getValue("TodoUrl");
  log.info('action started');
  return {
    type:    'GET_DATA',
    promise: request.get(API_URL)
  }
};
```

So if i want to write some logger info in Action files, i am not able to do
because it is requiring node modules and failing. This is happening during
web pack build it.

Action file executes both on cliet and server.

Not only logger files, we have some common modules which gets the API Urls also.

I need to get the URL information in action files.

Any direction will be appreciated.

Comment: What error are you getting with Webpack?

Comment: i solved this by adding env.BROWSER in webpack and added if condition.